# Opam installation error from source

Tags: ocaml, opam

The following error was obtained while installing opam from source

```
make -C ocp-build
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/14810/opam-master/ocp-build'
make[1]: `ocp-build' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/14810/opam-master/ocp-build'
make clone
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/14810/opam-master'
make -C src_ext
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/14810/opam-master/src_ext'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/14810/opam-master/src_ext'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/14810/opam-master'
make compile
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/14810/opam-master'
make -C ocp-build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/14810/opam-master/ocp-build'
make[2]: `ocp-build' is up to date.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/14810/opam-master/ocp-build'
ocaml shell/get-git-id.ml src/core/opamGitVersion.ml
./ocp-build/ocp-build -no-use-opamfind -init -scan  
Unknown option -no-use-opamfind.
make[1]: *** [compile] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/14810/opam-master'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

tried removing options from the makefile but did not work

Comment: Are you using the version from GitHub or the latest stable release (which is 1.1.0)?

Comment: What version of OCaml and what OS? Try anil's ubuntu aptitude repo if you can.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with both the latest git and stable release. OCaml version from git (4.02.0+dev3-2013-12-19) but (and I suspect this is the killer) it's on Fedora 13.

Comment: I just got the same error, recompiling opam with the new OS X Yosemite and Xcode 6.1